# Importing multiple GPX files using st_read()?

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, r-sf

Hi i have multiple gpx files stored in a folder and i wish to read all of then in one go using R's SF package and put it under different names.

I tried this code : just like how its explained in most of the tutorials for .CSV files

```
setwd("C:\\Documents")
mydir = "feb 19 - Copy"
myfiles = list.files(path=mydir, pattern="\\.gpx", full.names=TRUE)
myfiles
```

The result i got is:   character(0)

For the explanation purpose, the gpx traces can be freely downloaded from https://www.openstreetmap.org/traces and can be stored in a file and then explained

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your syntax looks ok to me. Are you sure that `feb 19 - Copy` is within `C:/Documnets`? Can you find it listed if you run `list.dirs()` ?

Comment: It looks to me as if you're searching for files whose *name* is `.gpx`, not those whose *extension* is `.gpx`.  What happens with `pattern=".+\\.gpx"`?

Comment: Thanks @nicolas and limey. I learnt that the file directory should have been "./gps/feb 19 - Copy" instead of "feb 19 - Copy". also after applying pattern=".+\\.gpx" as suggested by limey I was able to read the files. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved.
The mistake lies in the path of the directory as explained in the comment by Nicolas Velasquez. Checking for the problem using

```
setwd("C:\\Documents")
list.dirs()
```

and then verifying whether the folder is there or not. Through that code I identified that the directory is  "./gps/feb 19 - Copy"  and not just "feb 19 - Copy".
So my new code is

```
mydir =  "./gps/feb 19 - Copy"
```

And then reading the files using the following code chunk

```
myfiles = list.files(path=mydir, pattern=".+\\.gpx", full.names=TRUE)
myfiles
```